# Can I use private API in my application then upload to Google play market?

Tags: android

In my application, I used a snippet code below

```
public static void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
try {
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class<?> iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anyone know when I used this code in my application, Google still allows me to upload my app, or will prevent/reject - because it is private API / forbidden API?

Comment: If it works now, it will work in market too. You  can use reflection freely.

Comment: I just suspect the ability of my application when I upload to market, because the above code snippet will open mobile internet data automatically by using the function that mark "private" from sdk. Unfortunately, I don't have any account to upload to test my suspection now...

Comment: I got it. I have found an application on market that used the same above code, it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is supported, and even recommended in the situation where you want compatibility with multiple versions of the Android OS in one apk file.

You can check the article from android official blog about reflection.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html

Comment: Thanks. I have found an application that autoswitch 3G without user action: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.va.android
I've decompile that apk and found that they used the same my above code :D